# google drive open psm1 powershell wit script editor

Tags: powershell, google-drive-api, text-editor

How do I make google drive open my powershell files ( .ps1 / .psm1 / .psd1 ) ?

now it tries to open those file with google drive viewer ( which wants to play it as media ).

I don't need to be able to actually run these scripts, but I want to view them in a script project or Notepad alike interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view a script on `Google drive` online follow these steps:

1. Right click on the script in `Google drive` and go to `'open with'` >> `'Connect more apps'`
2. Search for an app called `'Anyfile Notepad'` and connect it
3. Right click on the script again and open it with `'Anyfile Notepad'`
4. Grant `'Anyfile Notepad'` access to your `Google drive` account

and you will be able to view the script online from `Google drive`. This will also allow editing of the file and saving it back to `Google Drive`.

Comment: That approach works for .PS1 files, but **doesn't work for .PSD1 nor .PSM1 files **

Comment: Have a try at connecting `Anyfile Notepad` instead of `Drive notpad` that might solve you problem (Answer has been corrected).